# Inserting data grid view selected rows into database using loop

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, insert

I have a some data that should be inserted into 4 tables one of these data are stored in data grid view selected rows , so I would loop through the data grid view selected rows to insert them into database I also used a method that do transaction and takes the SqlCommands as matrix and then proceed them one by one , but when I try to insert data it gives me the exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." in this line

```
cm[i].Parameters.Add("@car", Convert.ToInt32(newCarAdCarDgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
```

This is the transaction method:

```
public void ExTr(SqlCommand[] cm)
{
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cn.Open();
    }
    SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction();
    for (int x = 0; x < cm.Length; x++)
    {
        cm[x].Connection = cn;
        cm[x].Transaction = tr;

    }

    try
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < cm.Length; x++)
        {
            cm[x].ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        tr.Commit();
        MessageBox.Show("تمت عملية إضافة البيانات بنجاح");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        tr.Rollback();
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }
    finally
    {
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the code for insertion:

```
private void newAdSaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        count = newCarAdCarDgv.SelectedRows.Count + 3;
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cn.Open();
        }

        newCarAdClientPhoneTxt_Leave(sender, e);
        newCarAdClientEmailTxt_Leave(sender, e);
        newCarAdNotesTxt_Leave(sender, e);

        SqlCommand[] cm = new SqlCommand[count];

        cm[0] = new SqlCommand("insert into clientData (Id,clientName,clientWork,clientPhone,clientMobile,clientEmail) values (@id,@name,@work,@phone,@mobile,@email)", cn);
        cm[0].Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cm[0].Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", newCarAdClientNameTxt.Text.Trim());
        cm[0].Parameters.AddWithValue("@work", newCarAdClientWorkTxt.Text.Trim());
        cm[0].Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", newCarAdClientPhoneTxt.Text.Trim());
        cm[0].Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", newCarAdClientMobileTxt.Text.Trim());
        cm[0].Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", newCarAdClientEmailTxt.Text.Trim());

        cm[1] = new SqlCommand("insert into marketingData (m_Id,marketingDurations,marketingStartsFrom,marketingEndsIn,notes,adDate) values (@id,@durations,@start,@end,@notes,@date)", cn);
        cm[1].Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cm[1].Parameters.AddWithValue("@durations", newCarAdAdDurationTxt.Text.Trim());
        cm[1].Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", newCarAdStartDayDtp.Value);
        cm[1].Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", newCarAdEndDayDtp.Value);
        cm[1].Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", newCarAdNotesTxt.Text.Trim());
        cm[1].Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", newCarAdDateDtp.Value);

        cm[2] = new SqlCommand("insert into priceAndProfits (p_Id,marketingCost,marketingPrice,marketingProfit,dollarPrice) values (@id,@cost,@price,@profit,@dollar)", cn);
        cm[2].Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cm[2].Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", newCarAdCostTxt.Text.Trim());
        cm[2].Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", newCarAdPriceTxt.Text.Trim());
        cm[2].Parameters.AddWithValue("@profit", newCarAdProfitTxt.Text.Trim());
        cm[2].Parameters.AddWithValue("@dollar", newCarAdDollarPriceTxt.Text.Trim());

        for (int i = 3; i <= newCarAdCarDgv.SelectedRows.Count + 3; i++)
        {
            cm[i] = new SqlCommand("insert into carWorkCount (c_Id,carId) value (@id,@car)", cn);
            cm[i].Parameters.Add("@id", id);
            cm[i].Parameters.Add("@car", Convert.ToInt32(newCarAdCarDgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
        }

        ExTr(cm);

    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the final loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < newCarAdCarDgv.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
{
    cm[i+3] = new SqlCommand("insert into carWorkCount (c_Id,carId) value (@id,@car)", cn);
    cm[i+3].Parameters.Add("@id", id);
    cm[i+3].Parameters.Add("@car", 
      Convert.ToInt32(newCarAdCarDgv.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
}
```

Your code refers to Rows[i] but i starts with value 3 and you can go out of the number of rows if you select all the rows in your grid. Instead you just need to reference the commands with i+3

Comment: it gives me "index was out of bounds of the array"

Comment: On which line did you get the exception?